# Complement of the event: serving a non-faulted strong serve, within tennis

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Define the following events:
$A:$ non-faulted strong serve
$B:$ non-faulted weak serve.

Let ${P}(X)$ be the probabilty of event $X$ occuring. I was wondering what the complement of $P(A)$ is.
I think the complement of $P(A)$ is the probabilty that a player serves a faulted strong serve. Is this correct or does $P(B)=1-P(A)$ hold?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are all the possible outcomes?

Comment: " *I think the complement of P(A)
 is the probabilty that a player serves a faulted strong serve*" I do agree.

Comment: @callculus42 why? Is the event of serving a non-faulted weak serve not in the complement..?

Comment: Complement of A is weak serve or faulted serve.

Comment: List all possible outcomes (the sample space). Then, the complement of a certain event is all elements of the "list" (sample space..) other than itself.

Comment: @HappyDay The intersection of non-faulted weak serve and faulted strong serve is in the complement.

Comment: Presumably the exhaustive elementary events are:
\begin{align}
A:\ &\text{non-faulted strong serve,}\\
B:\ &\text{non-faulted weak serve,}\\
C:\ &\text{faulted strong serve, and}\\
D:\ &\text{faulted weak serve.}
\end{align}
If that's the case, then the complement of $\ A\ $ wouldn't be faulted strong serve (i.e. $C\,$) but faulted strong serve *or* weak serve (i.e. $B\cup C\cup D\ $).